# Why is the Android App process requiring less RAM the more times it is restarted?

Tags: android, performance, memory, service, ram

So i have been doing my thesis and while doing so i got some interesting results that i cant explain so may be somebody here with more knowledge of Android can.

### Short explanation of work

In one part of the thesis i was looking at performance of [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) with the Messenger implementation. While sending messages back and forth between an increasing amount of services measurements were taken on the core application that is using the different services. It is probably worth mentioning that each service is located in another app. So this means 1 service = 1 app whose only task it is to host the service.

These 2 tests were carried out

1. Measure RAM when connecting to an increasing amount of services
2. Measure RAM when sending messages to an increasing amount of services

### How measurements were taken

The RAM measurement was always taken after the connection the service had been established. Each data measurement was taken 5 times and then divided by 5 to provide an average. The app was restarted each time before taking a new measurement. To get the RAM usage the Android Monitor Memory Usage tool was used. This gave me a memory dump file like the one you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html#ViewingAllocations) under the *View overall memory allocations* heading. The data i have been looking at is PSS total of the process and it is kilobytes as mentioned in the file.

### How tests were run

In test 1 i started with 1 service taking 5 data point and then moving on to 2 and 3 and 4 and all the way up the 30 services simultaneously. When test 1 was completed i started with test 2 once again going back to 1 service and increasing up to 30.

### Results

(Note in the graphs i call each service a "module" for the sake of the thesis)

Here you have the plotted results for test 1 in a graph. Value is PSS.[image]

And here is the plotted results for test 2 in a graph Value is PSS[image]

So looking at this it look a little bit alright since the more services i use the less RAM the application is using. It is strange but at least it the same thing happens in both test cases. However when you put these to graphs next to each other i could see that it is actually a continuous slope down and the amount of services does not matter. When test 2 starts with 1 service it actually has the same RAM usage as test 1 with 30 services. This can be seen in the graphs, sadly i cant plot this in the same graph for you right know however i think you can see it clearly enough in the once i provided.

So the tests were carried out in this order

Test 1 (1 service -> 30 services)  -> Test 2 (1 service -> 30 services)

### So the question

What is going on here? I can not explain why the RAM usage is decreasing like this. The only thing i can come up with is if there is some built on thing in Android that optimise app RAM usage each time it is restarted. My knowledge into Android RAM and especially PSS measurements is not very high but hopefully all of this is not just one but stupid question.

I hope someone can explain this because i find it very interesting!

Thank you in advance

### Edit

As requested here is the private memory usage for test 1, my data files for test 2 have for some reason been mixed up and can not be trusted.

[image]

Alright so the private memory is going up as expected, however i would still like to know what is going on with the PSS values? My thinking is that since more services are being used there would also be more shared memory = higher PSS value? But that does still now explain how the PSS can be the same for test 1 with 30 services as in test 2 with 1 service.

Comment: What happens when you measure private memory usage instead of PSS?

Comment: I sadly don't have the private data plotted so it is hard to tell. Will edit my post when i got it. It was my belief that PSS gave a better estimation of how RAM heavy the app was compared to private memory, was this wrong? Lets say the private memory does not show a decrease, what could the cause of the PSS drop be then?